# What do I get for making new enemies?

Tags: relationship-mechanic, bubblegumshoe

Does my Sleuth get extra Relationship build points when the narrative gives me a new Hate, or is that only during character creation?

> The GM will create a Hate relationship for you, or you can work with her to do so. When you take a Hate, that Relationship starts at 3 for free, *and* you gain 3 build points to put into your other Relationships. [...] New Hates may be added later in play.
>  - "Like, Love, and Hate" BGS 27

It's unclear to me from the long paragraph I've partially quoted whether mid-game Hates grant 3 free Hate and 3 build points, or if that's only for character creation (which is the context of the paragraph: it's in the "Character Creation" chapter). If it *is* only at the start of the game, is there any guidance for mid-game Hates?

I'm especially confused about what happens if you use negative Cool to create a new Hate after a conflict ("Effects of Cool Damage" BGS 68).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where the Hate came from:

On p. 101, it explains what happens when you get a new Hate by GM action:

> GMs can add a 3-point Hate Relationship as a consequence of a throwdown or other major event. Unless the Sleuth went out of her way to earn the Hate, the player gains 3 Relationship build points to put into other Relationships.

But if a Love turns into a Hate, that's a Major Shift (p.98) and instead you are offered a Cool refresh to transform the Relationship:

> ...giving the Sleuth a Cool refresh of 5 points. If the Player accepts, the change happens.

On p.88 it is explained that the results of player actions do not earn the build points:

> Hates are a trade-off. They are a liability, and will make your life hellish. But at character creation, the GM awards you extra Relationship points if you have a Hate. Your friends may be more protective, bond more tightly since you've fought off this aggression together. You don't get that bonus if a Like or Love turns into a Hate, or if a new Hate appears during play thanks to the character's actions.

Comment: Do I also get the 3 relationship build points with a major shift? (The "but" you've used could suggest it's as opposed to that.)

Comment: @doppelgreener - that's not how I read it or how I intended it. Hope I've clarified it.

Comment: Ok, that's clearer. Sounds like you get that instead of 3 relationship build points in the current revision, you don't get a choice and you don't get both?

Comment: Sounds like I get nothing if I turn negative Cool into Hate after a throwdown; is there anything confirming that'd be going "out of her way to earn the Hate"?

Comment: That last paragraph might mean the first sentence (the current version of which I put there) ought to be revisited. O_O